# Close a tkinter progressbar window while matplotlib window is open

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tkinter

I am writing a program that does some work and uses matplotlib to plot some data. This can take some time so I set up a progressbar using tkinter. Threading with tkinter was not that easy. I am running the progressbar in the main thread and my working stuff in a substhread. However I can not close the progressbar window after my work is done, because apparently matplotlib does something in the tk root window. I don't know what. I added a minimal example of what I am trying to do. Notice that removing the line "plotsomething()" makes it do what I want: close the progressbar after work is done.

Can you please help me figuring out how I can close the progressbar window without closing the matplotlib windows?

```
# coding = utf-8
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading, queue
import time

def MAIN():
    PB = q.get()
    for i in np.arange(10):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(i)
        PB.step(10)
        PB.update()
    print("Done")
    
def plotsomething():
    x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
    y = np.sin(x)
    plt.plot(x,y)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Progress")
PB = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient = "horizontal",length=300, mode = 'determinate')
PB.pack()
q = queue.Queue()
q.put(PB)

plotsomething()

T = threading.Thread(target=MAIN(), name="MAIN")
T.start()
T.join()
plt.show()
```

Comment: So you want the progressbar to launch at startup, count to 10, print "Done", destroy itself, and then the matplotlib window will launch right?

Comment: As a side question, where would you have like to have looked in the documentation to find this? This question comes up about every other week in various forms which suggests that there is a documentation failure.

Comment: Looked at this question again, you really should post your edit as an answer.  To be cynical, I am getting rep for my half answer that you should be getting for your full answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting conflicting gui-main loops between the `TK` you are starting and the `TK` that `plt` is start.  If you want to use `matplotlib` with your own gui, you *must* embed it your self and you **can not** import `pyplot`.  All the behind the scenes magic that makes the `pyplot` interface wonderful is what is messing you up here.

For a tutorial see [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html), for how `mpl` does the embedding see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py).

Also see:

- [Unable to save matplotlib.figure Figure, canvas is None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538235/unable-to-save-matplotlib-figure-figure-canvas-is-none/17539468#17539468)
- [Python Matplotlib runtime error upon closing the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252566/python-matplotlib-runtime-error-upon-closing-the-console/17252649#17252649)
- [Matplotlib bar chart in a wx Frame instead of a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091993/matplotlib-bar-chart-in-a-wx-frame-instead-of-a-new-window/15093155#15093155)

Answer (score 0):

I am solving the problem now by drawing every window seperatly by using the matplotlib tk backend. Apparently PyPlot is interfering with the tkinter root windows.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import queue, threading, time

def center_window(window_parent, w=300, h=20):
    # get screen width and height
    ws = window_parent.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = window_parent.winfo_screenheight()
    # calculate position x, y
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    window_parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

def MAIN():
    PB = q.get()
    for i in np.arange(10):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(i)
        PB.step(10)
        PB.update()
    print("Done")

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")


f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a.plot(t,s)
a.set_title('Tk embedding')
a.set_xlabel('X axis label')
a.set_ylabel('Y label')


#a tk.DrawingArea
root2 = tk.Tk()

PB = ttk.Progressbar(root2, orient = "horizontal",length=300, mode = 'determinate')
PB.pack()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, root )
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

root2.iconify()
root2.update()
root2.deiconify()

center_window(root2)

q = queue.Queue()
q.put(PB)

T = threading.Thread(target=MAIN(), name="MAIN")
T.start()
T.join()

root2.quit()
root2.destroy()

tk.mainloop()
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17833544/2) to the question [Close a tkinter progressbar window while matplotlib window is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833544/close-a-tkinter-progressbar-window-while-matplotlib-window-is-open) by the OP [throwaway17434](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614477/throwaway17434) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>